# No mouse or keyboard at first screen of w7 install. Both work in BIOS setup

Tags: windows-7, windows

Clean install of Windows 7, 64bit on a Samsung Pro 840 SSD on a P9X79 Deluxe ASUS MB. USB mouse and keyboard work fine during BIOS setup but disappear on the first install screen of Windows. Tried answers I've seen but no go.

Comment: If it's an optical mouse, does the light go out as soon as Windows starts?

Answer (score 0):

You have UEFI bios. I just read the manual - there is a setting "Legacy USB Support", set it to ENABLED. It is in ADVANCED screen.

Comment: Mouse & Keyboard are Logitech M310 combo. Light isn't visible normally.  Legacy settings have no effect.  Frustrating!

Comment: Solved. Had to be plugged into USB2 only port. No backwards compatibility on USB3.

Comment: That's weird, i will try on my comp.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to help someone figure out why their install had this problem and here's a full checklist:

1. Try enabling Legacy USB support in your UEFI settings.
2. Try a USB2-only port, if your motherboard has one.
3. Try a PS/2 keyboard if your motherboard still has a PS/2 port.
4. Consider installing in a BIOS+MBR configuration, then converting to a UEFI+GPT setup after installation. (Caution: Not for the novice.)

I've been in situations where #3 was necessary when #1 and #2 didn't work, and I've been in situations where I resorted to #4 because I didn't have a PS/2 keyboard on hand.

(Though #4 [will be going away](https://liliputing.com/2017/11/intel-plans-end-legacy-bios-support-2020.html) so don't rely on it.)